# Notepad++: regular expression to find functions whose parameters are also functions

Tags: regex, notepad++

So I've got a big text file and I want to search the following text:
`"decode(max(ABC), null, '1', max(ABC) + 1)"`
I used regular expression in Notepad++ as the following:

```
*decode(\s*)\(([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^)]*)\)
```

But search result is not found.

Comment: <pedantry> Your params here are more likely the *return values* of functions, rather than functions themselves. </pedantry>

Comment: BTW, what's with that star at the front of your regex?  If you remove that, you should match at least part of what you're looking for.  That's about as close as you're gonna get, too, without going down the rabbit hole.  You'd basically have to count parens or use a recursive expression to match the whole thing, and Notepad++ apparently uses POSIX REs (which are exceedingly crappy compared to PCRE).

Comment: @cHao Notepad++ has had PCRE support since version 6.0.

Comment: @user694733: Ahh.  I have 5.9 for some reason.  That explains a bit.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking for here, but this captures all parameter text (I'm not sure why you would want to capture the potential whitespace between `decode` and the opening parenthesis, so I changed it to a non-capturing group: `(?:\s*)`).

```
decode(?:\s*)\((.*)\)[^()]*$
```

That is, it captures

```
max(ABC), null, '1', max(ABC) + 1
```

As far as parsing that down further, into individual parameters, that is a rabbit hole as suggested in another comment.

Note that this regex assumes that no more parentheses follow the closing one for the `decode` function call.

You can try it out here:

http://www.myregextester.com/?r=d8c41eb7#highlighttab

And I just discovered debuggex, so I'm posting their cool image, too  :)

```
decode(?:\s*)\((.*)\)[^()]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SnjV7MsUYgeZWwvo)

Comment: Actually, I'd add a word boundary before the decode: `\bdecode`